# How to Think in Sets

Tags: sql, t-sql, loops, foreach, sql-server-2008-r2

My company has Programs, Staff, Clients, and Events.  We want to audit two random client events for each staff in each program.

I created a query to select all staff who had a client event in the past six months in a program.

```
SELECT TOP(2) 
    program_id, staff_id, client_id, event_date
FROM 
    events 
INNER JOIN 
    client ON events.client_id = client.client_id
WHERE 
    <blah, blah> --by date range, program, client showed up at event ...
ORDER BY 
    NEWID() --randomizes the top 2 picked from this set
```

Now, I need to iterate through that for each staff member in each program.  Staff can serve in more than one program, in which case we audit two client events for each staff/program combo.

Results should be something like:

```
program_id  staff_id    client_id   event_date

p1  12345   abc123  8/26/2013
            xyz123  5/16/2013
p1  23456   bcd123  7/26/2013
            wxy123  4/16/2013
p2  12345   cde123  9/26/2013
            xyz123  3/16/2013
p3  34567   efg123  7/26/2013
            uvw123  5/16/2013
```

(Would be cool to spit this out to an xls with a separate tab for each program.)

Other folks have posted similar questions.  I am posting this because it is a pure example of how to think in sets.  Please help me iterate through that set.  Thank you.

Comment: Using SSMS is irrelevant.

Comment: @PowderSnorkel - If one of the answers provided your solution mark it as answered. Thanks  :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a few suggestions, but not quite a total answer.  One thing I would do is group by program_id in SQL so you're seeing each program with it's staff.

This address your last question - flatting the rows can be done with a self join.

```
SELECT lt1.program_id  
    , lt1.staff_id    
    , lt1.client_id   
    , lt1.event_date
    , lt2.staff_id    
    , lt2.client_id   
    , lt2.event_date

FROM youLastTable lt1
    Join youLastTable on lt1.program_id = lt2.program_id
```

Would produce this:

```
p1  12345   abc123  8/26/2013   xyz123  5/16/2013
p1  23456   bcd123  7/26/2013   wxy123  4/16/2013
p2  12345   cde123  9/26/2013   xyz123  3/16/2013
p3  34567   efg123  7/26/2013   uvw123  5/16/2013
```

For your first question, how to randomly get two rows by group, try grouping values and left me know if it works. For instance:

```
SELECT TOP(2) 
    program_id, staff_id, client_id, event_date
FROM 
    events 
INNER JOIN 
    client ON events.client_id = client.client_id
WHERE 
    <blah, blah> --by date range, program, client showed up at event ...
GROUP BY  program_id -- and possibly, staff_id
ORDER BY 
    NEWID() --randomizes the top 2 picked from this set
```

Comment: Good start. Now the primary challenge is to: 1. iterate through so that we have two client events for each staff.  2. spit the results out into separate xls tabs for each program.  Thanks!

Comment: Way cool!  Got that to work, almost the result I need.  BUT, at least you got me thinking in sets.  Thanks!  Now I am going to try the PARTITION BY example below.

Comment: I've found that it is tricky for many people to switch from looping to sets.  I often use temp tables or simple sets and go step by step so I can see the results of each step. That's why GROUP BY program_id in your first query will help you visualize and describe what you need for the second step.  That being said I'm fuzzy on randomizing, but I'm pretty sure grouping will help and @usr probably has the answer.

Comment: Good advice, thanks.  Both this method and the one below worked great.  New tools for the tool kit.  Not sure how ORDER BY NEWID() does it's thing, but very simple to add that to the end of a result set (which is sent to the select statement) and then set a TOP(?) in the select.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I've understood the requirements but you can surely adapt this to your needs. I understood them as "for each staff/program combination, draw two events at random".

I'd first calculate the possible staff/program combinations. Then for each combination we want to draw two random events:

```
WITH combinations AS (
 SELECT DISTINCT program_id, staff_id
 FROM events
)
SELECT e.*
FROM combinations c
CROSS APPLY (
 SELECT TOP 2 *
 FROM events e
 WHERE e.program_id = c.program_id AND e.staff_id = c.staff_id
 ORDER BY NEWID()
) e
```

`CROSS APPLY` means "for each outer row (drawn from `c` in this case) join the following rows to it".

Here's a different version:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
 SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY program_id, staff_id ORDER BY NEWID()) r
 FROM events e
) e
WHERE e.r <= 2
```

Much more elegant.

Comment: Testing this now, THANKS!

Comment: YES!  Did the PARTITION BY and then added and ORDER BY at the very end ORDER BY program_id, program_staff